# How do I point to multi-dimensional array values?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I need some help on multi-dimensional arrays... I cannot find out how to assign a value to an array in a void task, that was created in main.
i tried to find help all over the place, but the longer i keep reading the less i understand

Please help

```
void addValue(a,b)
{
  //somehow assign value to a[2][6] using pointers and such

void main()
{
  int dest[7][7] = { 0 };
  int a = 2;
  int b = 6;
  addValue(a,b);
}
```

Comment: Does it matter what language is used? You should add a language tag if so

Comment: @Makunda all fixed now :) thanks for the help

Comment: @mukunda doesn't work

Comment: @mukunda how would the compiler know the dimensions of **dest

Comment: somehow i thought a 2d array is a pointer array, `template<size_t s> void addValue( int (*dest)[s], int a, int b ) { dest[a][b] = 1; }` should work a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
void addValue( int (*dest)[7], int a, int b )
{
    dest[2][6] = 12;
}

int main()     
{
    int dest[7][7] = { 0 };
    addValue(dest, a, b);
}
```

Consider using `std::array` instead of C-style arrays; the latter are an anachronism in C++. You can make the `7` a template parameter in `addValue` if you want to support other dimensions of array.